# Cannot convert array to floats python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, floating-point

I'm having a problem that seems like the answer would be easily explained. 
I'm struggling to convert my array elements to floats (so that I can multiply, add on them etc)

```
import csv
import os
import glob
import numpy as np

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)                      
        return list(reader)

all_data = []

path=raw_input('What is the directory?')       
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):
     all_data.extend(get_data(infile))
a = np.array(all_data)
current_track_data=a[0:,[8,9,10,11,12]]
abs_track_data=a[0:,7]
```

and I get the error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) C:\Users\AClayton\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.0.3.1262.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):
> 
> C:\Users\AClayton\Current\python begin\code_tester2.py in <module>()
>      18 for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')): # performs loop for each file in the specified path with extension .csv
>      19      all_data.extend(get_data(infile))
> ---> 20      a = np.ndarray(all_data, dtype=float)
>      21 
>      22      current_track_data=a[0:,[8,9,10,11,12]]
> 
> ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32
```

Comment: Could you look over your code?  It doesn't match what's in the exception.  I see a few differences, including some indentation.

Comment: Can you as well show the output of line 19?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your script is not the same as the code you've posted... As the traceback of your error shows, in line 20 you are calling `np.ndarray`. That's the [numpy array object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), not the `np.array` [factory function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). Unless you know very well what you are doing, follow the docs advice and:

> Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty` (refer to the
>   See Also section below). The parameters given here refer to a
>   low-level method (`ndarray(...)`) for instantiating an array.

So change your line #20 to:

```
 a = np.array(all_data, dtype=float)
```

and you should be fine.

The error you are getting comes because `ndarray` takes your first input as the shape of the array to be created. There is a harcoded limit to the number of dimensions set to 32 on my Windows system (may be platform dependent, not sure). Your `all_data` list has more than 32 entries (or whatever that value is in your system), misinterpreted as sizes of dimensions, and that's what triggers the error.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake and the delay in reply. Thanks for the help on that matter, I whould have checked the elements for ndarray. Also I have now changed it to array and got the error:

 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I assume That is because I am still setting it with "all_data"?

Comment: I think I found the issue: all_data's last row was only half full of values. If I remove the bottom row it should work...